# How to access JSON values returned by AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have written AJAX code to fetch MySQL data and show it on an HTML page. But my output is not showing on the page.

What am I doing wrong?

### PHP:

```
function nav() {
    $this->dbConnect();
    $qry="SELECT pid, ptitle FROM pages WHERE pagepub='1' ORDER BY porder ASC";
    $result=mysqli_query($this->connect,"$qry") or  die('MySql Error!  ' . mysqli_error());
    $results = array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($results);
    $this->dbclose();       
}
```

Here is the output of my [PHP file](http://keralapsctuts.com/app/category.php):

```
[
    {
        "pid":"1",
        "ptitle":"One Time Registration Tips"
    },
    {
        "pid":"2",
        "ptitle":"First men in India"
    },
    {
        "pid":"3",
        "ptitle":"First Women in India"
    }
]
```

### JavaScript / HTML:

```
<div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text will be replaced</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://keralapsctuts.com/app/category.php',
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json', 
        success:function(data) {

            var id = data[0];              //get id
            var title = data[1];           //get name

            $('#output').html(" <a class='list-group-item' href='"+id+"'"+title+" <i class='fa fa-chevron-right pull-right'></i></a>");

        } 
    });
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: Have you looked for any errors in the console?

Comment: It looks like your PHP returns an array of rows, each row having a "pid" and "ptitle". That does not seem to be reflected in your JavaScript code. I suggest taking a look at the structure of the JSON.

Comment: I think you need something like `var id = data[0]['pid']; ` and `var title = data[0]['ptitle'];`

Comment: I havn't checked for error @JayBlanchard

Comment: @showdev can u check the my PHP now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you returning more rows, you should use `for` if you want to iterate through them.

```
success:function(data) {
  var result = "";
  for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var id = data[i]["pid"];              //get id
    var title = data[i]["ptitle"];        //get name
    result += "<a class='list-group-item' href='"+id+"'>"+title+"<i class='fa fa-chevron-right pull-right'></i></a>";
  }
  $('#output').html(result); //Set output element html
}
```

Comment: Can also use `$.each()`, since that was what it's designed for.

Comment: The `<a>` is missing its closing bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Given your output of:

`[{"pid":"1","ptitle":"One Time Registration Tips"},{"pid":"2","ptitle":"First men in India"},{"pid":"3","ptitle":"First Women in India"}]`

Your `data` would be addressable like so:

```
success:function(data){
    var id = 0;
    var title = "";

    $.each(data, function(k, v){
        id = v.pid;
        title = v.ptitle;
        $('#output').append("<a class='list-group-item' href='"+id+"'>"+title+"<i class='fa fa-chevron-right pull-right'></i></a>");
    });
}
```

Comment: But its not giving the output on the DIV

Comment: Just missing a closing bracket for `<a>`: `$('#output').append("<a class='list-group-item' href='" + id + "'>" + title + "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right pull-right'></i></a>");`

Comment: Fixed.Didn't see it the first time.

Comment: @Kannan, do you see any errors in your browsers JS Console? What are you getting?

Comment: You have marked one as an answer and both answers are using the same selector. When I tested, it worked fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/okc8ktk9/